# Payments & Smart Contracts

Tags: transaction, microtransaction, smart-contract

Can I build a payment platform with escrow features (smart contracts), for free money transfers on IOTA?

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts are in the works and will most likely be released this year.

In the meantime you may want to look into smart transactions. You can build a payment platform with escrow features on top of that. Here is a link of a demonstration

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=D7MY_autNs8&app=desktop

It uses IOTA flash channels as the basis.

Good luck!